# HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL Java servlet

Tags: java, servlets, http-status-code-405

Can someone please tell me why i am getting error:HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed ?
I am trying accomplish that after method doPost() ,user will be redirected to "/logout" controller ,where is invalidate session.
It's funny because method is called ,do everything what should do(update user in database), but after send to user error 405.Another  where i use doPost() (for example: LoginController)  working well ,but when i try compere and find bug ,i dont see any :<

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <form method="post" action="account">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email address</label>
                <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="email"
                       value="${sessionScope.loggedUser.email}" required aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                       placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input name="password" type="password" minlength="5" maxlength="40" required class="form-control"
                       id="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="repeatPassword">Repeat Password</label>
                <input name="repeatPassword" type="password" minlength="5" maxlength="40" required class="form-control"
                       id="repeatPassword" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Save changes"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@WebServlet("/account")
public class AccountController extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String email = req.getParameter("email");
        String password = req.getParameter("password");
        String repeatPassword = req.getParameter("repeatPassword");

        if (email == null || password == null || repeatPassword == null) {
            doGet(req, resp);
            return;
        }

        if (password.equals(repeatPassword)) {
            HttpSession session = req.getSession();
            User user = (User) session.getAttribute("loggedUser");
            user.setEmail(email);
            String sha1hexPassword = DigestUtils.sha1Hex(password);
            user.setPassword(sha1hexPassword);
            UserService service = new UserService();

            try {
                service.update(user);
            } catch (UpdateObjectException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            req.getRequestDispatcher("/logout").forward(req, resp);
        } else {
            req.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Passwords not the same");
            req.setAttribute("fragment", "account");
            req.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/index.jsp").forward(req, resp);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

Your doGet() method call is inside the server doPost() code. You should redirect the response, doGet is for recieving a GET request and any query string.

Comment: I have method doGet() in this servlet.it's only redirect to page *.jsp where i have this html code for client to update user. I can't redirect because when i do that ,request will sent do  destination and want to get inside to doPost() method . But why i should do that if my doGet() method  nicely send me to this one page if any of param is null.In sum  even if my block of code (if(....){doGet()}) doesn't execute ,or i just comment this, server still sent cient 405 error because" protocol.endsWith("1.1") ". And that i can't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Here:

```
req.getRequestDispatcher("/logout").forward(req, resp);
```

i should do

```
resp.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath()+"/logout");
```

because in "/logout" i have only doGet() method ,and if i use "getRequestDispatcher()" its try to find doPost() method.